# PHP Undefined variable with $this

Tags: php

I have got the following code in PHP:

```
class NewsletterDB {
private $connection;
public $last_query;
private $magic_quotes_active;
private $real_escape_string_exists;

function __construct() {
    $this->open_connection();
    $this->magic_quotes_active = get_magic_quotes_gpc();
    $this->real_escape_string_exists = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string");
    $this->$connection = "";
}

public function open_connection() {
    if (!isset($this->$connection)) die("error");
    $this->$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    ...
```

but I'm getting the following error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: connection in /Users/...

Why is that? I have defined the variable at the top after class NewsletterDB {...

Comment: Defined here: private $connection; and used here: $this->$connection = mysqli_connect... Also doesn't work if I define private $connection = "";

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's `$this->connection` not `$this->$connection`. The latter would mean: take the string contained in the local variable `$connection` and call the member variable with that name.

Comment: I have always wondered what `$this->$connection` means ...

Can I get some example snippet?